# Blank spaces in equations

Tags: equations, alignment

I'm writing a paper and I want to replicate this set of equations in my latex document. But when I'm trying to do the align with `&` many times I get error.

[image: Set of equations]

```
\begin{eqnarray}
    \label{Eq:GeosWind}
    \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} &+& \overrightarrow{v}\nabla u + \frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}  -fv +f^{\ast}w \mp v \frac{\vert\overrightarrow{v}\vert}{r}  + F_x = 0 \label{a}\\
    \frac{\partial v}{\partial t} + \overrightarrow{v}\nabla u + \frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial p}{\partial y} + fu \pm u \frac{\vert\overrightarrow{v}\vert}{r} +F_y = 0 \label{b}\\
    \frac{\partial w}{\partial t} + \overrightarrow{v}\nabla w + \frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial p}{\partial y} -g -f^{\ast}u  + F_z = 0 \label{c}\\
    I &&   II    III   IV    V    VI   VII
\end{eqnarray}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution with `alignat` (7columns) and `eqparbox`. I also loaded the `esdiff` and `esvect` packages for a simpler typing of partial differential, and nicer arrow tips:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[b]{esvect}
\usepackage{esdiff}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][M] {\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle#2$}}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    \begin{alignat}{7}
 \diffp{u}{t} &+{} &\vv{v}\nabla u & +{} & \frac{1}{\rho}\diffp{p}{x} & & & -{} & fv & +{} & f^{\ast}w & \mp{} & v \frac{\vert\vv{v}\vert}{r}& + F_x = 0 \label{a}\\
 \diffp{v}{t} &+{} & \vv{v}\nabla u & + {} & \frac{1}{\rho}\diffp{p}{ y} & & & +{} & fu & & & \pm{} &\eqmathbox[VI]{u\frac{\vert\vv{v}\vert}{r}} & +F_y = 0 \label{b}\\
   \eqmathbox[I]{\diffp{w}{t}} &+{} &\eqmathbox[II] {\vv{v}\nabla w } & +{} & \eqmathbox[III]{\frac{1}{\rho}\diffp{p}{y}} &-{} & \eqmathbox[IV]{g} & -{} & \eqmathbox[V]{f^{\ast}u} & & & & & + F_z = 0\label{c} \\
   \eqmakebox[I]{I} & & \eqmakebox[II]{II}& & \eqmakebox[III]{III} & & \eqmakebox[IV]{IV}& & \eqmakebox[V]{V} & & & & \eqmakebox[VI]{VI} & \phantom{ + }\text{VII} \notag
    \end{alignat}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. A very minor nit to pick: The first instances of `+` in rows 1 and 2 should be generated by `&+{}` instead of by `&{}+`, right?

Comment: @Mico: Not  so minor. The reason, I guess, was the way I ended in this code: I initialy wrote a standard alignat wiithout the roman numbers, then redistributed some of the &  so as to centre these numbers w.r.t. the above maths expressions, enclosed in   \eqmathboxes — and the ampersands were so many… Thanks again!

Comment: I've deleted one final stray `}` character. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've been a few hours trying to align the equations. So, ```alignat``` is a better way to that and the white spaces are represented with ```{}```. Right?

Comment: Not exactly – the distinctive feature of `alignat`, as opposed to align, is that it adds no space between the alignment  columns: it up to you to add the spacing. Here , I added `{}` after  `+` to ensure it's considered by latex as a `mathbin`, with the *ad hoc* spacing on each side (because there's a `&` before, it would be a `mathord` without this trick.